# How to get the Billing or Shipping address in Account objects as a single data?

Tags: account, address

Is there a way to get the billing or shipping address in account object as a single data? Currently the address data is split across several fields like

> Street 
>   Address
>   City
>   State
>   Zip
>   Country

Is there any field called "BillingAddress" exists? Please suggest.

Comment: Hi, I work on this. Out of curiosity, what is your use case such that querying the individual columns doesn't fit your needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/compound_fields_address.htm

After v30 Sfdc introduced compound field.This is read only field which is available on Account object

A sample SOQL will be as below

SELECT Name, BillingAddress
FROM Account

Comment: Thanks Mohith. I checked in salesforce.schema in eclipse IDE and did not find it. But now as per your suggestion it is working fine for me.

Comment: is there any field type in a standard or custom object to persists BillingAddress data. when i assigned the billingaddress data to a text field it throws error. Any suggestions pls